# How many pixels to see atoms?

Tags: science-based, biology

Human sight uses about 500 megapixels. Now, imagine someone who uses more than 500 megapixels (with the same width), I assume that he would see things more accurately. So my question is :
- how many pixels would he need to see cells or even atoms ?
Bonus :
- what determines the number of pixel of human sight ?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. As the name suggests, we like to solve worldbuilding problems. I fail to see a worldbuilding problem here. Can you make it clear? You can take the [tour] and visit the [help] to better understand what we expect. Also, please note we enforce a one question per post policy.

Comment: *"Human sight uses about 500 megapixels":* citation very strongly needed. (Hint: what is the maximum diffraction-limited resolution, knowing that the human eye has a focal length of about 22 to 24 mm, and a maximum aperture of *f* / 2?) (Second hint: in broad daylight the iris closes to about *f* / 8. What effect does this have on diffraction-limited resolution?)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The relation with world building is simple : I would like to introduce in my world enhanced humans with the ability to see things down to the level of the atomic structure. I only need a scientific justification of how it could be possible. Being far from a specialist of this field, I reduced the problematic to the number of pixels. If the justification should involve other notions such as focal, aperture, etc. - I will look for informations about that as well.

Comment: @user21102 Keep in mind that light isn't _that_ well behaved. It scatters, bounces, etc. Difraction alone would make that pretty much impossible, I think.

Comment: welcome to worldbuilding...

Comment: Simple answer: infinity would not be enough. Explanation: pixel count has little to do with resolution. Anyways, optical wavelength is not small enough to resolve individual atoms.

Comment: OK, I won't write an answer, but basically the thing is that even a perfect lens cannot project a point source of light into a point image: the point source of light is turned into a blurry disk (named an [Airy disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk) for the English physicist who computed this in 1828). The size of the disk, for a lens focused at infinity, is about $1.22 \lambda N$, where $N$ is the aperture, a.k.a. $f$-number. Remember, this is a *perfect* lens, with no defects; there is a maximum possible separation power. Sorry, but you cannot see individual atoms...

Comment: @user21102 that seems like important information that belongs in the question itself. You should edit the question appropriately to make your intent clear.

Comment: @user21102 - as pointed out in other comments, if you're looking for _scientific justification_, it's impossible because of the limitations of wavelengths of light.  You'd also need an impossibly huge lens (at least as far as fitting into the human skull is concerned).  OTOH, Superman can do it (in some of his incarnations), so you can just use magic.

Comment: To add to @AlexP's comment: remember, your enhanced human's cornea and conjunctiva are also made of cells and atoms. If his eyesight were that good, he wouldn't see anything past those

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's start by assuming your previous statement (which would be interesting if true) is accurate, and that humans really do see at 500 megapixels.

As found [here](https://www.sciencefocus.com/the-human-body/how-small-can-the-naked-eye-see/), the smallest object the naked eye can see is about 0.04mm.

We know that the average nuclear radius is in and around 1.2 femtometres- this is over one billion times smaller. In fact, to be exact, **seeing a hydrogen atom with the naked eye would mean your vision is 33.3 billion times more powerful than that of a healthy individual.**

Congratulations, you have a visual resolution of **16.8 exabytes**.

To get my bonus point, I believe you're referencing [this article](https://curiosity.com/topics/how-many-megapixels-is-the-human-eye-curiosity/), which says the lowest camera resolution people think is truly lifelike is 576 megapixels. Our brains are only capable of transferring this resolution of data along our optic nerves.

Cameras and the human optic nerve are incomparable in function: start reading into either how CMOS cameras work or photochemistry and you'll see why. Light on the whole is a tricky subject, but I guess if we wanted to measure the camera resolution of the human eye, you could take the smallest square we could theoretically see (0.04mm) and find out how many of those we could fit into our field of view. Interestingly, using some sphere math, we can only see **36.8 million** of these tiny 0.04mm squares at any one time, which should illustrate my point that cameras and eyes work very differently. We work with shapes and patterns, not ones and zeroes.

Edit: Just to be clear- seeing atoms with the naked eye is not justifiable scientifically. Interesting concept, though- keep working on it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

Comment: What you have left out is that the number of pixels is irrelevant.  The resolving limit will be determined by the wavelength of interest and the size of the lens aperture (diffraction limit).    That's why we  can only generate images of individual atoms with specialized scanning systems, using other than E-M radiation in the process.